# DDD Aggregates Validation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am building an application that will expose part of its features through RESTful services and my application packages is organized as below

1. Application --> This package contains the RESTfull services
2. Model --> Contains the domain model the aggregates, Value Objects,...
3. Infrastructure --> Contains the set of classes required to access the database
4. Mongo DB --> My DB

The application package exposes the endpoint

```
CastReview(UUID reviewedEntityId, string review)
```

The review the retrieved from the body of the request and it is mandatory.

Now my question is where the validation should occur

1. Should I keep the validation logic inside the aggregate and inside the application I just construct instance of the aggregate and check if the aggregate is valid
2. Or Should I have the validation inside the application package as well as inside the aggregate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Aggregates, I wouldn't call it validation but invariant enforcement, since they are supposed to be [always valid](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/). You don't just modify an aggregate and then have it checked by an external validator, aggregates enforce their own invariants.

Some rules are clearly domain invariants since you have to have deep knowledge of aggregate data to enforce them, and some are definitely applicative rules (e.g. email confirmation == email). But sometimes the lines are blurred. I would definitely check at a client-side and applicative level that the review is not null or empty, and at the same time I wouldn't consider a `Review` Aggregate OK if it has a null review, so I would do both. But this might be domain-dependent and YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Integrity constraints (or "invariants", if you prefer that term) should be defined in the (domain/design/data) Model. Then they should be checked multiple times:

1. In the front-end User Interface (**on input**/change and **on submit**) for getting responsive validation.
2. In the back-end Application or Infrastructure **before save**.
3. And in the DBMS (**before commit**), if your DB is shared with other applications.

See also my article [Integrity Constraints and Data Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/754323/Integrity-Constraints-and-Data-Validation).